# How to pass enum values to web service comsumed in Genexus 15?

Tags: java, jax-ws, genexus

I'm having trouble consuming a web service done in C# that has an enum attribute and a DateTime attribute. In Genexus 15, using Java Generator, 'JAX-Ws' is used to generate 'SOAP Native' web services.
Importing wsdl did not fail. However when sending the request the program gives the following error messages:

```
request: 
  <Route xmlns="http://www.jfdkfjdkfjkd.com.br/">
  <Id>0</Id>
  <Name>fdfd 2387</Name>
  <IssuerId>434343</IssuerId>
  <OriginCityId>1302603</OriginCityId>
  <DestinationCityId>50308</DestinationCityId>
  <Modal>Road</Modal>
  </Route>
```

The Modal attribute is enum type:  Road, Air, Train, Others

Importing wsdl did not fail. However when sending the request the program gives the following error messages:

```
No error.SOAP Fault: Error in client request.
Message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (11, 13). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: '' is not a valid value for ModalTypes.
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read7_ModalTypes(String s)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read11_Route(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read35_CreateRoute()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer40.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
Detail: (-20004)
```

How can I send enum attributes via web service in this case? Is there any way to configure JaxB in Genexus or wsdl manually?

In case of DateTime attribute the erro is as follows:

```
Detail: SOAP Fault: Error in client request.
Message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (12, 17). ---> System.FormatException: The string '
' is not a valid AllXsd value.
at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.ToDateTime(String value)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read14_Tracking(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read39_CreateTracking()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer48.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
Detail: SOAP Fault: Error in client request.
Message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (12, 17). ---> System.FormatException: The string '
' is not a valid AllXsd value.
at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.ToDateTime(String value)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read14_Tracking(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read39_CreateTracking()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer48.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
Detail: (-20004)
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

By for now

Answer (score -1):

you could define enum values in Genexus, however i dont know if this is enough 
do you know how to pass the Modal Value in  a correct way? 
It means:
   Road
It is no correct. What would be the correct ? 
could you try the webservice using  SOAP ui or something like that?

Comment: I will try use SOAP ui to test the web service.  In relation enum values, when I import wsdl the ModalTypes domain was build correctly, and SDT is Ok too.  Something like ModalTypes.Road,  ModalTypes.Air, ModalTypes.River and so on.

Comment: Could you send me the request provided by Soap UI? Or could you share me the Wsdl file of this Webservice? This information allow me to understand what is expected by the webservice